# Ignore .json files while converting typescript files into javascript files using tsc

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, tsconfig, tsc

I want to convert all the typescript files in a folder into javascript and put all those converted files in some different output folder. I am using the command `tsc --outDir dist_server express/**/*` to convert the typescript files into javascript files. Now, the challenge is that there are some .json files as well in the folder which tsc is not able to compile and convert to .js . How do I ignore these non-typescript files? Exclude option in tsconfig file isn't working as these files are not unit files, as in they are imported in some other .ts files because of which tsc is not able to ignore them. How do I ignore them or convert those config files into .ts files?